# Como pegar valores aleatórios de uma tabela no BigQuery (SQL)?

Tags: sql, bigquery

Estou com uma tabela onde eu tenho em uma coluna um número de registro e em outra o número de chaves cadastrada nesse registro.

Eu estou querendo pegar esses dados para análise, porém, como são milhões de números de registros, estava apenas querendo pegar uma amostra de 20.000 destes na condição do número de chaves ser "x".

Em resumo, eu preciso de uma função que extraia linhas randômicas (pois para minha amostra não vale a pena eu pegar na ordem da coluna).

exemplo da consulta:

```
SELECT id, chaves
FROM tabela
WHERE chaves BETWEEN 0 and 5
LIMIT 20000
```

No caso eu imagino que depois do `SELECT` tem uma função que gere valor randômicos (talvez algo como `random(id)`) ou então exista `ORDER BY RANDOM`, ou algo do tipo.

Answer (score 4):

Eu consegui colocando a função RAND() dentro do ORDER BY.

Ficou assim minha consulta:

```
SELECT id, chaves
FROM tabela
WHERE chaves BETWEEN 0 AND 2
ORDER BY RAND()
LIMIT 20000
```

Answer (score 0):

você pode usar o TABLESAMPLE SYSTEM (10 PERCENT) assim:

```
SELECT id, chaves
FROM tabela
WHERE chaves BETWEEN 0 and 5
TABLESAMPLE SYSTEM (10 PERCENT)
```

Aí você decide o percentual.

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).